# Override "user agent stylesheet" on focus

Tags: css

I have read many posts and tried quite many things but I don't seem to get an embed form to work the way I need it to work.

Problem with *input* on *focus*:

**1. Blue outline** > I tried the code below I seemed to work and then suddenly it stopped working.

```
input:-webkit-autofill:focus {
    outline: none !important;
}
```

**2. Yellow background** > I got it fixed with the code below.

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px #ffefef inset !important;
}
```

[I would like the form to always look like this (normal, hover, focus, active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mogmC.png)

But that's sadly not the case because of "user agent stylesheet".

**You can see the [form in live here →](https://loveorfear.co/)**

Also note, I am not a programmer. I know WordPress well enough but any tricky answers might get me confused. I would like to solve this problem either using .css or adding some JavaScript code in the header/footer element.

And I also tried [Normalize.css](http://nicolasgallagher.com/about-normalize-css/) which, I guess, I could just add to my theme folder with the same name... forgive my dummyness. If so, that didn't help. Well, I don't know if I was supposed to add a new line there or not.

Any help would be highly appreciated (praying hands).

Comment: applying `outline:0` appears to be working at least in chrome

Comment: Those stylings actually serve a specific purpose, and just “removing” them without providing any alternative to signal those states to the user is a rather dumb thing to do …

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#drip-first-name:focus, #drip-email:focus {
    outline: 0;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black !important;
}
```

make sure you prefix it for different browsers(Not sure if needed) and of course do the same for active etc (wherever you get that blue outline) . This will work for chrome.

However, a few notes. since you're messing with css you need to start using Chrome Devtools. It's free and built into chrome. This will show you what's wrong and how to fix it.

Secondly, using `!important` in css is not a major no no but the reason your `border-bottom` rule wasn't working was because you had already used `!important` in a previous class and it was picking it up. Important won't let you override anything unless it's lower in the CSS stylesheet and is also marked as important. Long story short at some point you will have to redo the whole thing if you keep using important.

this is how it would look to you with devtools open:

[image]

This is the link for you to get started with devtools:
[Devtools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/)

Comment: Thanks. I had tried that before as well, and I tried once more but even with that, I don't seem to get to display the bottom border. I wish for the form to look exactly the same when its active but with or without the "outline: 0" I still don't get the bottom border. I tried ...

#drip-first-name:focus, #drip-email:focus {
    outline: 0;
 border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}

... in hopes but no luck.

Is there a way to get rid of the outline and also have the bottom border?

Comment: Oh i didn't actually notice the bottom border disappears. I'll check it tomorrow that I'm at work and let you know. No worries I can find a solution for it. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @ElsaSaks I've updated my answer. This should work for you. You will probably need to check other browsers and use prefixes (haven't tested this in all browsers). Also, I've added a bit of advice to make your work easier in the future. All the best.

Comment: I totally missed the !important rule. Oopsy daisy. Now that you, and Zohir mentioned it I am not surprised I didn't get the results I wanted. I also removed the other !important rules which role I understand but had blind spots after not working on websites for a while. Thank heaps! Also, I use DevTools non-stop. Its a heavenly gift to the world of bright minds.

Comment: Let me ask one more thing... you wrote "make sure you prefix it for different browsers" and I will admit - I don't actually know how to do that. I could Google or if you have any quick, helpful tips on where to get a comprehensive answer then I am open to that.

Comment: Ok, before you actually get an answer i have to ask a question. Are you going to dwelve into css or is it something you're doing only once? Here's the quick answer but there are also automated solutions for frontend development that I can talk to you about if you're actually going to do css for a long time:

https://www.lifewire.com/css-vendor-prefixes-3466867

just to clarify not everything needs prefixing in css and I'm still too bored to check if outline does. Also, if you have your solution, mark one of the answers as a solution because there are other people that will stumble on it.

Comment: First, I don't see a way to mark any useful answer as a solution. Nothing visual. I scanned twice. But I would love-love to do that.

Comment: Secondly, I see myself to swelve in CSS. I have done so in-depth this year, and for few projects I see that its necessary which I also enjoy.

So automated solution sound neat. I just don't know much about frontend myself. But I am open to hear and explore and learn.

Comment: OK, you're going to have to use Gulp or Webpack then. Gulp is easier to use but it's slowly getting outdated. https://gulpjs.com/ Then Webpack is harder to setup, but has a lot more power: https://webpack.js.org/ If you ask me you should start with webpack and yarn https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/ . I can't explain everything on here, take your time to see what's what. They will also help you with your js skills. You basically make a setup to minify and compile css and js and sprites and blah blah. You set it up once and works for most things. oh and devtools of course.

Comment: Thanks a million. This is golden yet beyond my skillset. Once I have resources, I will work with a developer to fix weaknesses in my projects. For now, I take the rusty path.

Comment: You crack me up :) I already have heaps of challenges. No need to add one that is not gonna bring me value as the others do. Its focus. I keep learning other things while I leave a form of learning mentioned here to others. Let them (you) have the piece you've worked for :D

Answer (score 1):

apply `outline:0` to the input normal style not `:hover` or focus, then remove 
`border-width: inherit !important;` from the `:focus` of the input, because  then it takes it's parent border width, and that is `0px` therefore your border disappears on focus.

Comment: thank you :-* goodness, I guess I was half-sleeping, I totally missed the !important rule. Precious feedback ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Well if you'd like you can remove all the default userAgent-styling by using the `all: unset;` ? That works for me.

But if you just want to remove the outline you shall do
`input { outline: none; }`. Hope that helps.

Edit: the `all: unset` is there for remove all `user Agent Stylesheet`. Nothing else.

Comment: That might override other styles for the element, and will have to write styles again for different state. Can you specify which all styles will be unset?

Comment: @bhansa the default ones, for example if we take the `a` -tag the `unset: all` will have `color: #00f;text-decoration: underline;`, but your styling will not be deleted. Just to be safe: you can put the `unset: all` at the top of the css of that element.

Comment: I tried this { all: unset }. I got an error for { unset: all } Also, I didn't like how it unsets everything. But thanks.